# Is there an MVC Helper Method that can be used to get the name of a form element?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

With ASP.net MVC I have a Model like so:

```
public class Project {
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    // SNIP ...
}
```

My View contains:

```
@model Project

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectName)
```

I would like to write some javascript that references the textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ProjectName').someMethod();
</script>
```

I don't want to hard code ProjectName in there. Ideally, I would like to use a helper method to get what the name is, just in case I refactor and rename the property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#@Html.NameFor(m => m.ProjectName)').someMethod();
</script>
```

Is there something like this that I can use? I don't want to use a CSS class to trigger this, because I want to put this in an Editor Template and I don't want the code to execute for every instance of the class for every text box. I want it to execute for the one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `Html.NameFor` / `Html.IdFor` helpers in the ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly (Microsoft.Web.Mvc) which you can pull through NuGet and work exactly like that using lambda/expressions instead of literal string property name.

Comment: Awesome I didn't realize they had it in there.

Comment: I meant to say the MVC Futures assembly (Microsoft.Web.Mvc) not MvcContrib - corrected my answer.